# Where do I get the Splintered oar?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Splintered oar is a two-handed sword with the shape of an oar; one of the few magical, blue, items that are also unique. Before patch 1.0.4 it was legendary.

Some suspect it has some relation to the Black Rock ledgers. Others consider it just an in-game collectible.

Where do I get the Splintered oar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It drops in hell difficulty only.

Go to Act I; travel to Wortham; in front of the church, find Ul and kill him.